# CSV import not working - Need Assistance

Tags: import, magento-1, csv

We have a scenario where `schools.csv` file will be uploaded under `schoolsearch` folder under the Magento root directory. This should update the `schools` table under Magento database. But since migration its not working. We are using a module for this task. But its not working. The following is the content of `observer.php`

```
class Attigo_Schoolsearch_Model_Observer
{
    protected function getfilepath()
    {   
        Mage::getBaseDir(). DS .'csv'. DS . 'schoolsearch/schools.csv';

    }

    public function schoolDetail()
    { 

        $row=array();
        //$filePath = $this->getfilepath();
        $filePath = "/var/www/html/main/schoolsearch/schools.csv";


    if (($handle = fopen($filePath, 'r')) !== FALSE) 
        {
            $i=0;
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, '\t')) !== FALSE) 
            {

                    if($i==0)
                    {
                        $i++;
                        continue;
                    }

                     if($data != "")
                     {
                        foreach ($data as $school) {
                         //   echo $school.'';
                           $row=explode("\t",$school);

                        }

                        $school = Mage::getModel('schoolsearch/schools');

                        $school->setKundnr($row[0]);
                        $school->setSkola($row[1]);
                        $school->setBadress($row[2]);
                        $school->setBadress1($row[3]);
                        $school->setBpostnummer($row[4]);
                        $school->setBpostort($row[5]);
                        $school->setFakturamottagare($row[6]);
                        $school->setFakturaadress1($row[7]);
                        $school->setFakturaadress2($row[8]);
                        $school->setFpostnr($row[9]);
                        $school->setFpostort($row[10]);
                        $school->setBadressid($row[11]);
                        $school->setFakturaadressid($row[12]);
                        $school->setBcountrycode($row[13]);
                        $school->setFakturacountrycode($row[14]);
                        $school->save();

                       // print_r($school);
                       // echo $row[13].'->'.$row[14].'';


                     }

            $i++;
            }            
        }
        else
        {
            echo "permission denide";
        }
    }
    public function AddCustomerGroup(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
            $_post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();

        try {

            $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

            $customer->setData('group_id', $_post['group_id']); // or whatever the group id should be
            $customer->save();

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            echo $e->getMessage;
        }


    }


}
```

Can any one help me where it goes wrong?

Comment: On which event observer trigger? Any error while you trying to import

Answer (score 1):

Replace your schoolDetail function to following code :

```
public function schoolDetail()
    { 

        $fileLocation = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'importexpert/schools.csv';
        $mageCsv = new Varien_File_Csv(); 
        $data = $mageCsv->getData($fileLocation);   
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
            $school = Mage::getModel('schoolsearch/schools');
            $school->setKundnr($row[0]);
            $school->setSkola($row[1]);
            $school->setBadress($row[2]);
            $school->setBadress1($row[3]);
            $school->setBpostnummer($row[4]);
            $school->setBpostort($row[5]);
            $school->setFakturamottagare($row[6]);
            $school->setFakturaadress1($row[7]);
            $school->setFakturaadress2($row[8]);
            $school->setFpostnr($row[9]);
            $school->setFpostort($row[10]);
            $school->setBadressid($row[11]);
            $school->setFakturaadressid($row[12]);
            $school->setBcountrycode($row[13]);
            $school->setFakturacountrycode($row[14]);
            $school->save();
        }

    }
```

Put your schools.csv under **media/importexpert**/ folder and clear the cache run the code again.Hope it will work.

Comment: Great information.